# Laravel - storing into session from service provider?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, service-provider

I am using GeoIP package to get the user's IP and translate it into a zipcode. I don't want to do that for every request that the user is making but rather do a one time IP to zipcode, store it into session and then when I need to use it just check if the zipcode exists inside the session.

I tried to place the code inside AppServiceProvider@boot but it does not work. It is not remembered into the session. I tried inside routes but not working as well.

**edit**
The code inside boot method of appserviceprovider. This is just a test.

```
If (! Session()->has ('zipcode'))
    Session(['zipcode' => geocodeZipcode()]);
```

The problem is that this runs everytime since the zipcode is not persisted in the session. The if is never false from my tests so far.

Where do I need to put the code to store the zipcode into the session and have it remembered even if the user is not logged in?

I basically need something like this:
1- User accesses a page on the server for the first time (any page)
2- I get the user IP and translate it to a zipcode
3- I store the zipcode into the session
4- For every other request the user makes I check if the zipcode exists into the session. If not I execute step 2.
5- Use the zipcode for its purpose

Where should I place the step 2 and 3?

Comment: Can you show us the code you had for your AppServiceProvider?

Comment: Added the test code.

Comment: Why don't you use the excellent Laravel cache mechanism? : http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/cache. This is made for use-cases like you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel the **session is initialized via middleware**, and all the middlewares execute after the service providers boot phase

This is the reason why in your service provider you can't access the session: it has not been initialized yet

You should place your steps 2 and 3 in a middleware:

```
class ZipCodeMiddleware
{
    public function handle( Request $request, Closure $next )
    {
        //ZIP CODE NOT FOUND IN SESSION: CREATE IT AND STORE
        if ( ! Session::has( 'zipcode' ) )
        {
            //get ip and translate to zip     
            //store zip in the session
        }    

        //use zip code here or access it later from Session

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Once you've stored the zip code in the session, you can access it from a controllers directly from the session, or, you could instance a class in the middleware and re-access it later with:

```
 //use zip code here or access it later from Session
 $zipClass = new ZipClass( $zipCode );
 App::instance( ZipClass::class, $zipClass );
```

This way you can auto-inject the `ZipClass` depencency in your controllers and Laravel will give you back the `$zipClass` instance you built previously in the middleware

Comment: Okay, that makes sense now. I'll try it and see if that solves my issue. Bte, I did not know I can do class injection in middleware. Thanks, learned two things.

Comment: @Cristian : if the answer was useful, please consider voting/accepting it :)

Comment: All is working fine. I did not wanted to mark it as solved until I had the time to test it. Thank you!